# SharePoint 2013 REST API: How to get Document Kind field of Document library?

Tags: 2013, document-library, rest, managed-metadata

I want to get Document Kind filed title, but with following request I am getting only these data:

```
<SITE_URL>/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('<DOCUMENT_LIBRARY_NAME>')/items()?$select=Document_x0020_Kind
```

[image]

I receive same response if I use:

```
..../items()?ListItemAllFields
```

I need a normal Label, not Id in Label. Can someone help?

Comment: Is this column created by you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 3 options :

**Option 1** - if the document library is at the site collection level, you can use the below endpoint with a GET call.

```
/_api/web/Lists/GetByTitle('<DOCUMENT_LIBRARY_NAME>')/items?$select=Title,TaxCatchAll/Term&$expand=TaxCatchAll
```

**Option 2** - If you know the ID of the list item, then you can use the below endpoint with a GET call.

```
<SITE_URL>/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('<DOCUMENT_LIBRARY_NAME>')/items(1)/FieldValuesAsText
```

**Option 3** - you can use the below POST method if the document library is at the subsite level.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "https://Site_url/_api/web/Lists/GetByTitle('<DOCUMENT_LIBRARY_NAME>')/GetItems(query=@v1)?@v1={'ViewXml':'<View><Query></Query></View>'}",
    type: "POST",
    headers: {
        "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
        "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()
    },
    success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        for (var i = 0; i < data.d.results.length; i++) 
        {
              if(data.d.results[i].Document_x0020_Kind != null)
              {
                    console.log(data.d.results[i].Document_x0020_Kind.Label);
              }
        }
    },
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log('error')
    }
});
```